# Example JPA - creating dynamic query - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a method controller which gonna return all advertisements that are being filtered by passed paremetrs.

```
@GetMapping("/search/advertisements")
    public List<Advertisement> getSpecicShortAdvertisements(
            @RequestParam(value = "city", required = false) String city,
            @RequestParam(value = "category", required = false) AdvertisementCategory category) {
        return shortAdvertisementService.getSpecificShortAdvertisements(city,category);
    }
```

So for example it can be: `http://localhost:8080/search/advertisements?city=WARSZAWA&category=ANIMALSCARE`

but it can be also `http://localhost:8080/search/advertisements?category=ANIMALSCARE`
If I do not send any parameters it shoudl return all advertisements.

It would be so hard to write query for every single parameter, so I've used `Example`, but do not know why it returns empty list all the time despite having data in DB.

It's being added for every run of application (initial data)

```
advertisementRepository.save(Advertisement.builder()
                .advertisementCategory(AdvertisementCategory.ANIMALSCARE)
                .dateTime(LocalDateTime.now())
                .description("LAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
                .featured(false)
                .photos(null)
                .title("TiTitle 2tle 1")
                .city("KRAKOW")
                .build());

        advertisementRepository.save(Advertisement.builder()
                .advertisementCategory(AdvertisementCategory.ANIMALSCARE)
                .dateTime(LocalDateTime.now())
                .description("LAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALA" +
                        "AALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAAA" +
                        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4AAAALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
                .featured(false)
                .photos(null)
                .title("TTitle 2Title 2Title 2itle 2")
                .city("WARSZAWA")
                .build());
```

So as you can see if I send 'WARSZAWA' as an city it should return this advertisement, but it returns nothing.

Service method:

```
public List<Advertisement> getSpecificShortAdvertisements(String city, AdvertisementCategory category) {
        Advertisement example = Advertisement.builder()
                .advertisementCategory(category)
                .city(city)
                .build();

        return advertisementRepository.findAll(Example.of(example));
    }
```

Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface AdvertisementRepository extends JpaRepository<Advertisement, Long> {

}
```

//EDIT

SQL generated:

```
select advertisem0_.advertisementid as advertis1_0_, advertisem0_.advertisement_category as advertis2_0_, advertisem0_.city as city3_0_, advertisem0_.date_time as date_tim4_0_, advertisem0_.description as descript5_0_, advertisem0_.featured as featured6_0_, advertisem0_.title as title7_0_ from advertisement advertisem0_ where advertisem0_.featured=? and advertisem0_.advertisementid=0 and advertisem0_.city=?
```

If I made

```
public List<Advertisement> getSpecificShortAdvertisements(String city, AdvertisementCategory category) {
        ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAny();

        Advertisement example = Advertisement.builder()
                .advertisementCategory(category)
                .city(city)
                .build();

        return advertisementRepository.findAll(Example.of(example, exampleMatcher));
    }
```

then it returns everything despite sending `http://localhost:8080/search/advertisements?city=LALA` which should not match anything

Comment: How does the generated SQL statement look like?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli is there any way to check this

Comment: set the looger to debug: logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug